# how to load different styles for different components in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am using multiple components with a common layout and a login page with no layout.
my app.js looks like:

```
    return (
    <>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
      <Route path="/" element = {<Layout/>}>
        <Route index element={<Main/>}/>
        <Route path="/main" element={<Main/>}/>
        <Route path="/employeeaddedit" element={<Employeeaddedit/>}/>
        <Route path="/employeeedit/:id" element={<Employeeaddedit/>}/>
        <Route path="/employeelist" element={<Employeelist/>}/>
      </Route>
      {/* error page */}
      <Route path="*" element={<Error/>}/>
    </Routes>

    </>

  );
}
```

style.css is being imported in the components using layout but not in login component.
But when login component renders, it also gets the style of style.css which causes conflicts in the body style.
I want login to use only login.css style nothing else, how to do it?

Comment: Make sure that you are not importing `style.css` in your application main file (usually `index.js`)

Comment: I am not, i am importing css file individually in each components, but when i start the app, login page opens but also get style.css in its source.

Comment: Try prefixing the class names in login component with “login-“ to ensure that there’s no conflict. Of course, you should do same in login.css. I believe there’s a class name in login components that appears in the layout. Let me know if this works for you